# Basic ping pong style C++ program, can't seem to get it to compile and run

Tags: c++

To start off I must say I am an absolute n00b. I just started with C++ and I am trying to figure it out. To issue I am having is I found this source code on google for Ping Pong and I've saved it as "pong.cpp" from sublime text edit to my Desktop. I am under the impression that all C++ programs have to be run through the terminal? but I am not sure, again beginner problems. So in terminal I direct it to my desktop in from there I type in g++ pong.cpp. Then it says this:

```
pong.cpp:2:10: fatal error: 'allegro.h' file not found
#include <allegro.h>
```

1 error generated.
I am thinking this is because I found it on google and that I need a file to back up the processing on the program which is unavailable.
Does anyone know where I could get a proper Ping Pong C++ code that would suite what I need here? I just want to be able to run a basic pingpong style game through my terminal to get more familiarized with C++

Comment: Here is the original code:

Comment: Do you have Allegro installed on your system?

Comment: The compiler doesn't know where to find `allegro.h`.  Allegro is an API for audio output, which presumably you have installed somewhere.  You need to tell the compiler where its headers live.

Comment: I have allegro installed. How do I tell the complier where the header is?

Comment: Where is Allegro installed? What compiler are you using?

Answer (score 2):

You have to tell gcc where allegro.h is installed. Run this command in terminal and post the output.

```
find / -name 'allegro.h' 2>/dev/null
```

Comment: This should be a comment, but answerer does not have the requisite 50 rep. Upvoting to initiate.